# Protractor cannot perform click actions within while loop inside an element.all statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, protractor

in the while loop within the element.all statement, I am trying to highlight an element on a table by clicking on it, then clicking the remove button followed by 'OK' on a confirmation popup.

The problem is that when I run protractor, it looks like the while loop is only iterating through rows on the table - ie: only items[j].click(); and j++ seem to be executing in the while loop, whereas my two jquery clicks are not executing until once at the very end.  Am I missing something special for while loops within an 'element.all then statement'?

Please help!

```
it('ADD MULTIPLE CAMERAS AND VERIFY', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:3000');
    var singleCamsToAdd = 5;
    var multiCamsToAdd = 2;
    var totalCams = singleCamsToAdd + multiCamsToAdd - 1;
    var newDesign = element(by.css('[ng-click="fileManager.newFile()"]'));
    var addCamera = element(by.css('[ng-click="design.addCamera()"]'));
    newDesign.click();

    //Multiple cameras added as many different rows
    for(i=0; i<singleCamsToAdd ; i++)
        addCamera.click();

    //Multiple cameras added in one camera row
    var quantity = element(by.css('[ng-model="cameraForm.qty"]'));
    quantity.clear();
    quantity.sendKeys(multiCamsToAdd);

    //Verify # rows corresponds with # cameras
    element.all(by.css('tbody[class ="bso ng-scope"] tr')).then(function(items) { 
    expect(items.length).toBe(singleCamsToAdd);
    expect(items.length + (multiCamsToAdd-1) ).toBe(totalCams);

    var j = 0;
    while(j < items.length) {
        items[j].click();
        $('[ng-click="editCamera.delete()"]').click();
        $('[data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();"]').click();
        j++;
    }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't the problem is with looping, but the waiting. Try waiting for the modal before clicking on it:

```
var modalLocator = by.css('[data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();"]');
element(by.css('[ng-click="editCamera.delete()"]')).click();
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(modalLocator), 5000);
element(by.css(modalLocator)).click();
```

If you modal is already in the dom when the page loads, you may need to just wait for it to become visible:

```
var modal = element(by.css('[data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();"]')); //hidden element
element(by.css('[ng-click="editCamera.delete()"]')).click();
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(modal), 5000);
element(by.css(modalLocator)).click();
```

**UPDATE**
Also, try moving elementFinder calls into the loop, it might be that at some point the dom structure changes and protractor cannot find previously found elements in the dom (that is just my guess):

```
var rowsLocator = by.css('tbody[class ="bso ng-scope"] tr');

element.all(rowsLocator).then(function(items) { 
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        elements.all(rowsLocator).get(i).click();
        $('[ng-click="editCamera.delete()"]').click();
        $('[data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();"]').click();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... doesn't seem to be working for me.  after I click items[j] note that the remove button has the same css, but represents a different item that is being removed.

Comment: It always clicks the remove button the first time and it's OK confirmation, but after that it just crashes for some reason... I have no idea why "nosuchelementError"

Comment: Yes, that did it! Life saver!!!! I owe you one my friend.  I'm still a little bit confused as to why items[i].click() did not work, but element.all(rowsLocator).get(i).click() worked.  I'd like to prevent this situation from happening in the future.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  Is there a place where you get your protractor API from other than the AngularJS protractor API page, i find its not 100% complete there.

Comment: @Bieksa, glad to have helped. I find elementExplorer mode to be a good place to explore and debug protractor, definately check it out. As for why `items[i].click()` is not working - my guess is that there are destructive operations in between the clicks happenning in your dom. PS Don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that you are **not** performing jQuery clicks in your loop as you claim in your question. [Protractor overrides the $ operator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=build$) so what you are doing is creating an ElementFinder that will asynchronously find the element then perform a click action on it.

So I believe the issue is that `items[j].click();` resolves quickly since the element has already been found, but `$('[ng-click="editCamera.delete()"]').click();` and `$('[data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();"]').click();` resolve slowly because they need to locate the elements in the DOM, all of which causes timing issues as you repeatedly loop over this block. I would recommend pulling in a library to expressly handle asynchronous looping, such as [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). I believe you can accomplish your goal with the [`eachSeries()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) function like this:

```
async.eachSeries(items, function(item, callback) {
  item.click();
  $('[ng-click="editCamera.delete()"]').click();
  $('[data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();"]').click();
  callback();
}, function(err){
  throw err;
});
```